# Im new to VB and cant seem to get the results of mySQL statements to be displayed on the form labels

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im not getting any errors so if anyone can point out what im missing/doing wrong it would be much appreciated

```vb
con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
con.Open()
'Count parcels
sql = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE DeliveryZone = ""UK"""
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)**strong text**
da.Fill(ds, "lblTPD2")

'sql = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE DeliveryZone = ""UK"""
'da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
'da.Fill(ds, "lblTPD2")
'lblTPD2.Text = sql
'If READER.Read() Then
'lblTPD2.Text = READER.GetString(0)
'End If
'lblTP.Text = ds.Tables("lblTPD2").Rows.Count.ToString

'Find and display averages
sql = "SELECT AVG(DeliveryCost), AVG(Weight) FROM tblBooking WHERE Zone = ""UK"""
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.Fill(ds, "Average")

lblAW.Text = ds.Tables("Average").Rows(0).Item(1) & " kg"
lblAC.Text = "£" & Format(ds.Tables("Average").Rows(0).Item(0), "0.00")

con.Close()
```

Comment: Is anything being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try your SQL statements outside of your VB project first?
If you did you will see that you can't use double quotes, `"UK"` to denote a string because " is not allowed. Use single quotes, `'UK'`.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE DeliveryZone = 'UK'"
```

and

```
sql = "SELECT AVG(DeliveryCost), AVG(Weight) FROM tblBooking WHERE Zone = 'UK'"
```